# AppEngine Datastore Admin does not work with federated login

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

When I click on "Datastore Admin" in my AppEngine (Python27) application with federated login, the following error shows up:

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /_ah/login_required?continue=https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~lpgng2 was not found on this server.
```

Seems like I am redirected to the /_ah/login_required page on admin instance and not on the frontend instance.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid as soon as you select **"Federated Login"** your code would need to handle requests to `/_ah/login_required` in order to serve any requests that requires login. Datastore admin is just a built-in app, which have its handlers requiring login.

Implementing this should resolve this. Hope it helps!

Comment: I can only handle /_ah/login in the application instance(where I do it), but I can not handle it in the dataadmin instance (which seems to be a special application instance since some time).